# Sleep function strange behaviour in signal-driven app

Tags: c, linux, signals

for my real-time systems classes i have to do a logging application based on signals. I have one thread, which is waiting in a infinite loop (sem_wait) to receive a specific signal and then it's supposed to create a dumpfile. In the main thread, I'am using sleep function to give me some time for testing until my threads get cancelled and application terminates (i know i could use pthread_join instead of pthread_cancel - it's only for testing).

Apparently, when the main thread goes into sleep and i'm receiving the second dump signal, it looks like sleep goes off and aplication terminates (after the first signal it's okay). When not using the sleep function application works fine. Now i'm wondering what could happen to sleep or maybe i should look for the error somewhere else?

Example code of my app:

```c
int main(){
   lib_init(); //here are the threads initialized
   sleep(60);
   lib_close(); //there we have pthread_cancel;
}
```

```c
void dump_handler(){
   sem_post(&sem);
}

void* dump_thread_fun(void*){
   while(1){
   sem_wait(&sem);
   //dumping happens here   
   }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give us more details, and preferably a [mre].

Comment: In particular, for the [mre], show how you are sending the signal. If it is not specifically a thread-directed signal, it may be delivered to the main thread, thus interrupting the `sleep` call.

Comment: The first signal doesn't terminate the application, the second one does.

Comment: `sleep()` is not a thread synchronization function.  Per [the POSIX `sleep()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/sleep.html): "The `sleep()` function shall cause the calling thread to be suspended from execution until either the number of realtime seconds specified by the argument seconds has elapsed **or a signal is delivered to the calling thread** ..."  Use `pthread_join()` or `sem_wait()` or another actual thread synchronization function.

Comment: @Barstok *The first signal doesn't terminate the application, the second one does.*  How are you installing your signal handler?  This is why a *complete* example is important.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: They are not really using `sleep` to synchronize threads; it is just to keep the main thread out of the way while the worker thread is exercised.

Comment: As @EricPostpischil said, it's used only to stop main thread from cancelling worker thread, it has nothing to do with worker threads or their synchronization. I know that i can do it in much better way, but i'm curious what is happening with it

Comment: @Barstok Is your code working?  What part of "only to stop main thread from cancelling worker thread" does **not** involve the interaction of different threads?  It doesn't matter what you call it - using `sleep()` is broken.  A process has no control over other processes sending signals.  If you want to wait for another thread to do something, **wait for another thread to do something**.  That **is** "thread synchronization".

Comment: @EricPostpischil "wait for another thread to do something" is pretty much the real-world definition of thread synchronization.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It is an academic exercise, and the main thread is essentially just a placeholder, not part of the signaling exercise.